# Horizontal line in with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

In Tikz environment, suppose I have nodes A and B. I know the (x,y) coordinate of point C relative to the northwest of A. I also know the x-coordinate of D relative to the northeast of B. How can I draw a horizontal line from C to D? Thanks
[image]

Comment: `\draw (shift={(x,y)}A.north west) -- (shift={(x,y)}B.north east);`

Comment: @percusse Thanks. But, I don't know y of D relative to B.north east.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `-|` syntax:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw] (A)at (0,0) {\rule{0pt}{3cm}A} ;
\node[draw] (B) at (3,0) {\rule{0pt}{5cm}B} ;

\coordinate (C) at ([shift={(-1,3)}]A.north west);
\coordinate (Dx) at([xshift={1cm}]B.north east);


\draw (C)node[left]{C} -- (C -| Dx)node[right]{D};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]